# Handle unique number validation on Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a table with input type number on the loop with total 5 records. If user select values between 1 to 10 on the input box and need a validation **"Select Unique values only"**, if user select same values on the input.

I would like to display the error message outside the ngfor loop. I have a function validateUnique to return the boolean value to display the error message.

My code:

```
    validateUnique(t, j): boolean {
    let res = true;
    const control = this.testFormControls.controls;

    for (let i = 0; i < control.length; i++) {
        if (t.value.rank === control[i].value.rank) {
            res = false;
            break;
        } else {
            res = true;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

I really appreciate the clue to display the error message outside the loop only one time. if validation fails...

Comment: You can make some variable which would hold value of validation of all elements - iterate over all inputs and if atleast one is having duplicate - skip checking the rest. How about adding div(if you are using container or template) under your for loop with condition `*ngIf='!youVarHoldingInfoIfInputsAreUnique` - it should give you expected result. Anyway that's nice idea to make some custom `Validator`, it would be good lesson.

Comment: Thanks you Mac Ryze